# Multiple form with same EntityType with different choice_value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have a problem with my Symfony 5.2 :

- I make a request with data who's going to a `FormType` with `EntityType` `Foo::class` but with a `choice_value` set on `code` field
- I do some payload modification and I forward my request to another Controller

```
$response = $this->forward('App\Controller\OrderController::create', [
    'request' => $request->duplicate(null, $refactorPayload))
]);
```

- In my new controller I use another `FormType` with `EntityType` `Foo::class` but with a `choice_value` set on `id` field  this time and I get this error `"Unable to reverse value for property path "foo": The choice "10" does not exist or is not unique."`

I search in vendor with my debugger and it seems to be the `Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\AbstractChoiceLoader` who 'cache' the list with the first `EntityType` and not clear it for the second

Comment: This sounds like a bug! You should report it to the Symfony bug tracker: https://github.com/symfony/symfony . Please try to provide a reproducer (a github project with the example where it's not working or just clear & short code sample in the issue)

Comment: done : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42206